# VS Code: How to remove message box when writing code

Tags: visual-studio

[vs code message img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgMjK.png)

How do you remove this box that comes up when writing code? Im not sure what this box is called which has limited me in trying to find this answer through google

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the VS feature called IntelliSense. There are configuration options for it so that you can adjust it to your liking.